# why XOR gives a bad result?

Tags: matlab

I started learning matlab and I have a problem with this code. Can you help me and explain why XOR gives a bad result? Regards :)

```
jawny = 'Ala010#';
jawny = dec2bin(jawny,8)


haslo = 'Olaf3@1';
haslo = dec2bin(haslo,8)


wynik = xor(jawny,haslo)
```

Comment: What result did you get?  What did you expect?  Did you verify that the intermediate results are what you expect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're confusing [`xor`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xor.html), which does a value comparison of zero or not-zero, with [`bitxor`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bitxor.html), which performs a bit-wise exclusive-or of two integer arguments:

```
jawny = 'Ala010#';
haslo = 'Olaf3@1';
jawny = uint8(jawny);
haslo = uint8(haslo);
wynik = bitxor(jawny,haslo);

jawny = dec2bin(jawny)
haslo = dec2bin(haslo)
wynik = dec2bin(wynik)
```

This code displays:

```
jawny =
    1000001
    1101100
    1100001
    0110000
    0110001
    0110000
    0100011
haslo =
    1001111
    1101100
    1100001
    1100110
    0110011
    1000000
    0110001
wynik =
    0001110
    0000000
    0000000
    1010110
    0000010
    1110000
    0010010
```

Comment: One more notch for the mentalist badge! :)